# AtomicInteger.lazyset() - visibility delay

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, memory-barriers

I was reading various posts about `lazySet()` method on AtomicInteger, which in-short denotes that visibility of the set value might not be immediately propagated to other threads (it is not a full barrier).

I ran a simple Demo, with multiple readers and one writer. readers periodically read value from AtomicInteger and the writer every 10 ms updates the value. I saw no distinguishable difference between `lazySet()` and `set()`. Is it due to x86 and strong coherency model? or sthe store buffers are simply quickly drained?

Comment: That question does not answer real use case results and why there is no visible difference in visiblity across threads

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon If you hadn't seen, and wanted to address.

Comment: Accepted answer for duplicate question contains `but may be reordered with subsequent operations (or equivalently, might not be visible to other threads) until some other volatile write or synchronizing action occurs).`. So if you code uses some syncrhonization actions (e.g. timer-related), there is no difference with `set()`.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as this question is specifically concerned with the differences in delay of visibility.